# Java - Detect if application outputs sound

Tags: java, audio, detection

For my weekend project I'm trying to create a simple program that waits for a program/process to output any sound, and when/if it does then do something.

in pseudocode:

```
if (application.outputsSound()) {
    /* Do something */
}
```

For starters it could be any sound coming from the specific application, but if it's within reason to detect a specific sound based on a stored audio file, that would be really cool.

My thoughts:
I guess that I need some kind of native library (JNI / JNA), but since I'm new to that, it would be really neat if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Interesting question. I think you'd need to interface with your audio driver or a least your OS to retrieve the processes calling it for audio processing. It must be possible in Java, although it would probably be easier in C/C++ since most low-level software like those we are talking about are coded in those languages

Comment: On modern operating systems, mixing is done in a user-space process which acts as an audio server rather than a device driver.   None the less, achieving this is platform dependant.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you could use the *IAudioSessionEnumerator interface*

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368281(v=vs.85).aspx

Although this is not perfect, as third party audio stacks will not show up, like ASIO.

On Linux it depends on what kind of environment you are using.